# Extended the User model, but not quite sure how to serialize fields for both User and UserExtended

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I extended my `User` model with a new model just called `UserExtended`:

```
# Django imports
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class UserExtended(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    crm_guid = models.UUIDField(unique=True)     
    security_q1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    security_a1 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    security_q2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    security_a2 = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    attempts = models.SmallIntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=0)
    key = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
    key_expires = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
    method = models.CharField(max_length=4, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_user_extended'
```

I was hoping by just doing that some Django magic would take care of the rest and I wouldn't have to change my `views.py` or `serializers.py`. But when I send a request to the end-point I get:

```
[api] django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Field name `guid` is not valid for model `User`.
```

So it does apparently need to be specified. I've been looking at the documentation and similar SO questions to find an answer.

This is what I have for my `views.py`:

```
# Django imports
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Third party imports
from rest_framework import generics
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAdminUser

# App imports
from users.serializers import UserSerializer


class UsersListCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = User.objects.all()
        email = self.request.query_params.get('email')
        username = self.request.query_params.get('username')
        if email:
            queryset = queryset.filter(email=email)
        if username:
            queryset = queryset.filter(username=username)
        return queryset


class UserRetrieveUpdateDeleteView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    permission_classes = [IsAdminUser]
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

For my `serializers.py` I just have:

```
# Django imports
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from users.models import UserExtended
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

# Third party imports
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'last_login', 'first_name',
                  'last_name', 'username', 'email', 'is_active', 'guid']
```

If I change `model = User` to `model = UserExtemded`, then I'll get an error like:

```
[api] django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Field name `last_login` is not valid for model `UserExtended`.
```

I'm thinking I need to do one of two things:

1. Create a serializer class for both models and call them both from the `views.py`. I've toyed with this a little by trying to pass a list or tuple in of `serializer_class` (apparently singular for a reason).
2. Setup the relationship in the `serializers.py`. I'm looking into this now.

Suggestions for how to resolve this issue?

Comment: You can look this link .three ways to extend User model in Django https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a different serializer and viewset to operate on `UserExtended`
My suggestion would be keep old serializer as is and create UserExtendedSerializer

```
class UserExtendedSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = UserExtended
        fields = "__all__"
```

and viewset would be simply:

```
class UserExtendedViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = UserExtendedSerializer
    queryset = UserExtended.objects.all()
```

this should solve your issue